# how can i set replicated Pods create rate or freeze time?not HPA

Tags: kubernetes

I want to create a deployment or StatefulSet with 3 replicates.it should create replicates one by one,not at the same time.does it support set create rate or freeze time?

Comment: for example,first pod create at first minute,second pod create at second minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider StatefulSets to run your deployment.
Make use of the below two properties to control the ordering and the frequency for the replica pods.

```
1. OrderedReady pod management policy
2. minReadySeconds
```